# Java Select Query String with parameter

Tags: java

This is the query

```
 String query = 
 "SELECT idPlayers 
 FROM pendu.players 
 WHERE first= 'Super'AND last='Man' AND pass=12345";
```

I want to change (first='Super') to  the  first = tboxFirst.getText() etc

Thanks for helping me

Frank

Comment: Take twain's advice regarding prepared statements. This is just screaming SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah - what you happen if someone entered **`foo'; delete from pendu.players;`** into the text box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a string you can just create the string with the value in it like this:

```
 String query = "SELECT idPlayers FROM pendu.players WHERE first= '" + tboxFirst.getText() + "'AND last='Man' AND pass=12345";
```

You should also take a look at [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) as that's a much better solution.

Comment: What you happen if someone entered **`foo'; delete from pendu.players;`** into the text box?

Comment: @Bohemian I agree that it's a bad decision to use Strings directly that's why I linked him to PreparedStatement as that's a much better solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
  PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT idPlayers FROM pendu.players WHERE 
       first= ? AND last= ? AND pass=?");

   pstmt.setString(1, tboxFirst.getText());
   pstmt.setString(2, ....);
   ....
```

Comment: just about the right example I'm looking for, I thought my syntax for a parameterized query is wrong. Turns out I just placed the set string earlier than the preparedstatement i created, and hence getting null results in my query, haha.

Answer (score 0):

String query = "SELECT idPlayers FROM pendu.players WHERE first=('"+tboxFirst.getText()+"') AND pass=12345";

Answer (score 0):

You can use either 
`String query = 
 "SELECT idPlayers 
 FROM pendu.players 
 WHERE first='"+tboxFirst.getText()+"'AND last='Man' AND pass=12345";`

or

`String query = String.format(SELECT idPlayers 
 FROM pendu.players WHERE first='%s'AND last='Man' AND pass=12345",               tboxFirst.getText());`

And if you are using JDBC, you can use PreparedStatement 
`PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT idPlayers FROM pendu.players  WHERE first=? AND last=? AND pass=?");`
`pstmt.setString(1, "Super");`
`pstmt.setString(2, "Man");`
`pstmt.setString(3, "12345");`